# [question deleted because not relevant]

Tags: go-ethereum

[question deleted because not relevant anymore]

Comment: Time = 2-4 days, and I've taken margins of about 800% here. The whole thing can probably be accomplished in a few hours. Budget - depending on the country of payment...

Comment: I don't think it should take a month. First bullet is probably a few minutes. First part of the second bullet (link SC to FE) also sounds like a few minutes job. Not sure about the QR code thing though, I don't have too much knowledge on that, in order to quote a time-frame. First part of the third bullet (deploy SC) also sounds like a few minutes job. Not sure what you mean by "push the site online", and with regards to "make sure everything is working fine" - I think that's your job, not the contractor's.

Comment: Share a link to the SC code and a link to the FE code, and I'll see if I can help. You're welcome.

Comment: SC: https://github.com/dice2-win/contracts/blob/master/Dice2Win.sol (open source as long as we credit the author)

Comment: FE: https://ibb.co/kS2J784

Comment: You do realize that you don't have to remove anything from the SC, right? You can simply not use it (whatever you don't wanna use) from your FE. So the task can be minimized to deploying the SC and granting your account permission to withdraw ether from it (might require additional code in the contract).

Comment: Good news, very nice advice sir. Let’s discuss by email if you have time to help. If not no worries you’ve been very helpful. u.zhang@protonmail.ch

Comment: Btw the edit part was so players have a smaller contract to read and can review it faster and see game is fair @goodvibration

Comment: Yup, that makes sense.

Comment: With regards to your FE, do you have a link to the actual code (rather than the web-page)?

Comment: I do but prefer not to share publicly , hope you understand sir

Comment: Can you share how long it is?

Comment: Super simple, very few lines

Comment: And you want to refactor only the part which interacts with the contract?

Comment: Front end is new and from scratch, all the linking contract part needs to be done

Comment: The second bullet says "Link the smart contract to our responsive front end". What does that mean in terms of functionality (i.e., what functions do you want to link)?

Comment: The whole etheroll game functions

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to submit / share the opportunity with crypto / blockchain job listing sites like https://twitter.com/jobsincrypto?

We submitted one opening and now we're getting resumes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're very welcome.